# The strong twin conjecture can be transformed into the unsolvability of a particular Diophantine equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, diophantine-equations, quantifiers, twin-primes

Let us consider the strong twin conjecture:
For all positive integer $n$ there exist a prime $p$ such that
$$n+4<p<2^n2^4$$ and $p$ is a prime and $p+2$ is a prime

Since the inequalities and the set of primes are both Diophantine, we can construct a polynomial $P(X)$ such that the strong twin conjecture is equivalent to the following statement:

For all positive integer $n$ there exist a prime $p$ such that $P(X)=0$ where $X$ is a vector of several variables.

Now, in a book by Matiyasevich's: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/hilberts-10th-problem

The author claim that the strong twin conjecture can be transformed into the unsolvability of a particular Diophantine equation.

Then my question is: How one can find this Diophantine equation or I am asking about a reference containing this equation.

Comment: This equation will very probably be incredibly complicated - just look at the prime generating polynomial with $26$ variables.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I know about that. I just wondering if there is an approach to reduce the problem to the the unsolvability of a particular Diophantine equation.